# Impossible to click on a Button

Tags: java, button, events, javafx

I am trying to add a button in a HBox itself in a borderpane : the top is the hbox and the center is a rotating Earth. However, I can't click on the button or even the TextField...\

I looked into it for a long time, trying to change the property of FocusTraversable, MouseTransparant, adding an EventFilter etc. but it's impossible to click on the button.
I thought it was maybe the events set on the scene but even removing them don't solve the problem, I'm at the point where I am thinking about creating a separate windows... Do you have an idea ? Here is the code :

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private final String SPACE_BACKGROUND = getClass().getResource("images/space_background.png").toExternalForm() ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Création du borderpane parent

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane() ;
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image(SPACE_BACKGROUND),
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT,
                BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT))) ; // Mise en place de l'image de fond
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10)) ;

        // Ajout des champs gérant la timeline

        HBox hbox = new HBox() ;
        Button button_date = new Button("Travel To") ;
        TextField date = new TextField("Enter a date") ;
        ChoiceBox<String> country_choice = new ChoiceBox<String>() ;
        Button button_go = new Button("Go !") ;
        
        new DefaultUIControler(button_date, date, country_choice, button_go) ;

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(button_date, date, country_choice, button_go) ;
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT) ;

        // Ajout du globe dans le borderpane

        StackPane globeContainer = new StackPane();
        root.setCenter(globeContainer) ;
        root.setTop(hbox) ;
        globeContainer.setPickOnBounds(false) ;

        // Création de la scène & Paramètrage du stage, pour la Terre
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED) ;
        scene.setFill(Color.BLACK) ;
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/style.css").toExternalForm()) ;

        primaryStage.setScene(scene) ;
        primaryStage.setTitle("A history of the world") ;
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("images/icon.png"))) ;
        
        primaryStage.show() ;

        // Ajouts à la scène principale

        EarthUX earthux = new EarthUX() ;
        Sphere earth = earthux.getEarth() ;
        AnimationTimer timer = earthux.getTimer() ;
        globeContainer.getChildren().add(earth) ;
        
        // Zoom
        scene.setOnScroll(new ZoomEventHandler(earth)) ;
        // Drag pour tourner la Terre
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(new DragEventHandler(earth, timer)) ;
        scene.setOnMouseReleased(event -> { timer.start() ; }) ;

    }

}
```

ButtonTravelEventHandler.java

```
public class ButtonTravelEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private TextField tf_date ;
    private ChoiceBox<String> country_choice ;
    private Button button_go ;

    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m" ; 
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m" ;

    public ButtonTravelEventHandler(TextField date, ChoiceBox<String> country_choice, Button button_go) {
        this.tf_date = date ;
        this.country_choice = country_choice ;
        this.button_go = button_go ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("test");

        // Récupère le texte + Gestion erreur
        
        String text_date = tf_date.getText() ;

        try {

            int date = Integer.parseInt(text_date) ;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // DO NOTHING
            ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now() ;
            System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "[LOG " + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy z")) 
                + "] Error while parsing the value in the textfield. A date should be an integer !" + ANSI_RESET) ;

        }

        // Récupèration des infos sur les pays par rapport à la date  

        
        
        // Affichage reste composants + Affectations aux choix


        
        country_choice.setVisible(true) ;
        country_choice.setManaged(true) ;
        button_go.setVisible(true) ;
        button_go.setManaged(true) ;
        
    }

}
```

And DefaultUIController :

```
public class DefaultUIControler {

    private Button button_date ;
    private TextField date ;
    private ChoiceBox<String> country_choice ;
    private Button button_go ;

    public DefaultUIControler(Button button_date, TextField date, ChoiceBox<String> country_choice, Button button_go) {

        // Affecte les composants

        this.button_date = button_date ;
        this.date = date ;
        this.country_choice = country_choice ;
        this.button_go = button_go ;

        // Spécialise les composants
        actualiser() ; 

    }

    private void actualiser() {

        // Choix du pays invisible au début par défaut
        country_choice.setVisible(false) ;
        button_go.setVisible(false) ;
        country_choice.setManaged(false) ;
        button_go.setManaged(false) ;

        // Style

        button_date.getStyleClass().add("button_date") ;

        // Actions
        button_date.setOnAction(new ButtonTravelEventHandler(date, country_choice, button_go)) ;

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance ! :)

PS : I tried this in the CSS,

```
        .button_date {
            -fx-background-color: lime ;
        }
        
        .button_date:hover {
            -fx-background-color: red ;
        }
```

The color is set to lime by default but doesn't change when hovered.

Comment: Assuming you're not consuming any and all events in an event filter registered with an ancestor of the button or text field, my guess is that some node is overlapping the button and text field. Nothing stands out to me from the code you provided that would cause this. Perhaps you can try to use [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) to inspect the scene graph of your application, though I don't know if that tool works with the latest versions of Java/JavaFX. Otherwise, I think we're going to need a proper [mre] (← read the linked help page for strategies to create one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I did a github so you can test and see the whole code : https://github.com/Jupiter41/bug
I'll try to look into it with the Scenic View, I didn't know about this software !

The only location where I consume an event is in the DragEventHandler class but like I said it also doesn't work without using this event and without the event.consume()

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your answer, Slaw (you made me discover Scenic View) and trashgod (for forcing me to do a minimal reproducible example) !

I solved my problem while doing the example, I removed every "not necessary" line and parameters and it worked when I replaced:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

by

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
```

The `true` is the depthBuffer, I didn't look into the details but I guess it's because of this parameter.

Comment: It's possible making the scene 3D (that's what setting the "depth buffer" to `true` does) was interfering with normal operations of the 2D controls, though I haven't used 3D much. But if you want a 2D HUD/controls, but include 3D stuff, you might want to look into using a 3D `SubScene` (and set that as the center of your `BorderPane`).

Comment: Depthbuffer or z-buffer (in blender) is in charge of what is in front or underneath in 3d scenes